# JS/PHP <--> embedded PHP HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I’m beginner to JS/PHP/MySQL development. I want to populate a select HTML element with table (nearly 4000 Records) from MySQL DB, relevant code is below.

```
<body onload="jsonload()">
<label>Beneficier Employee:</label>
<select item class = "BenEmpNo" name = "BenEmpNo" id = "BenEmpNo" onchange="jsEmpNoOnChg()" >
</select>
</body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function jsonload()
{
    let jsSelBenEmpNo = document.getElementById("BenEmpNo");
    let jsBenEmpNoDataAry;
    jsSelBenEmpNo.innerHTML = "<option value='-select-'>-Select-</option>";
    oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open('POST', "../php/oh-get_BenEmpNo.php", true);
    oReq.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    oReq.onload = function () {
            jsBenEmpNoAry = this.responseText.split('|');
            for (let i = 1; i < jsBenEmpNoAry.length; i++)
            {
                jsBenEmpNoDataAry = jsBenEmpNoAry[i].split('~');
                jsSelBenEmpNo.innerHTML += "<option value='" + jsBenEmpNoDataAry[0] +"'>" + "(" + jsBenEmpNoDataAry[0] + ")" + jsBenEmpNoDataAry[1] + "</option>";
            }
        }
    oReq.send("parsparm=" + "|");
}
</script>
</html>
```

---- PHP ---

```
<?php
$sql = "select EmpNo, EngName from beneficiary";
$ResultSet = "";
require_once("oh-dbcon.php");
if ($result = mysqli_query($db_con, $sql))
{
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
        {
        $ResultSet = $ResultSet . "|" . $row[0] . "~" . $row[1];
        };
    $ResultSet = $ResultSet . "~OK";
}else
    $ResultSet = "ERROR Result (" . mysqli_error($db_con) . ")-(" . $sql . ")";
mysqli_close($db_con);
echo $ResultSet;
?>***
```

When I used pure JS (XMLHttpRequest) it takes long time (around 50s) to populate the select, during which the page is froze.
But when using HTML embedded PHP code, it is almost instantly populating the select element (below code).

```
<label>Beneficier Employee:</label>
<select item class = "BenEmpNo" name = "BenEmpNo" id = "BenEmpNo" onchange="jsEmpNoOnChg()" >
    <option value = "-Select-">-Select-</option>
    
<?php
include("ohdadbcon.php");
$sql_phrase_ben = "select EmpNo, EngName  from beneficiary";
$qry_result_ben = @mysqli_query($db_con, $sql_phrase_ben);
while ($row_ben = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry_result_ben))
{
?>
    <option value = "<?php echo $row_ben['EmpNo']?>" >
<?php 
        echo $row_ben['EngName'] . "  |   " . $row_ben['EmpNo'] ;
?>
    </option>
<?php
}
mysqli_free_result($qry_result_ben);
?>
</select>
```

I want to use JS request only. Is there any other way or workaround for the slowness to this request?, or I’m doing something wrong here?

Comment: Right, so what is your problem? I would say that a dropdown with 4000 entries is going to be next to useless as a selection mechanism

Comment: Unrelated fyi: `language="javascript"` is for oooold browsers, deprecated and can be removed

Comment: As is `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: Mostly a guess.... Modifying the DOM 4000 times is going to keep the browser pretty busy.  Try storing all of the new elements in a string and then add that string to the DOM after the loop.

Comment: Thank you all.
RiggsFolly :
So what your suggestion to use instead?

Comment: Instead of `jsSelBenEmpNo.innerHTML +=`, use a variable, and then outside of the loop use `jsSelBenEmpNo.innerHTML =` with your variable

Comment: The page will have a drop-down with 4000 values?  Remind me never to use that page.   Would you like to discuss alternative UI approaches?

Comment: I prefer to build the whole page using PHP.  Only dynamic things (which is rare) need to be done with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

2 options... Tweak to only modify the DOM once:

```
let options = '';
for (let i = 1; i < jsBenEmpNoAry.length; i++)
{
    jsBenEmpNoDataAry = jsBenEmpNoAry[i].split('~');
    options += "<option value='" + jsBenEmpNoDataAry[0] +"'>" + "(" + jsBenEmpNoDataAry[0] + ")" + jsBenEmpNoDataAry[1] + "</option>";
}
jsSelBenEmpNo.innerHTML = options;
```

OR

You could also potentially generate the select or options list with PHP, and have THAT returned via AJAX. Then all the JS has to do is add/replace a single element in the DOM. This will move the entire loop to the server instead of the browser.

Though as others have mentioned, 4K items in a drop-down is going to be slow (not to mention very hard to use) just due to the size of the list. I would expect machines with low resources to get a bit choppy when the select is opened.

Comment: Many Thanks to you all.
I'll try that.